# Can I create an HTML page using javascript in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I know there is a way to load an html page

```
win.loadURL("index.html");
```

But, can I just load an html page when it's not from a file, just dynamically generated by javascript?

For example:

```
str = generateHtmlPage();
win.loadstr(str);  // just load from a string
```

Comment: Check this out: https://gist.github.com/dannvix/dc0efdbb75bf79a79d1c#file-electron-main-js-L21-L27

Comment: thank you. may i ask, is there a max length of this dynamic html content?

Comment: That should be a matter of how much memory Electron can get allocated from the system. There should be no virtual limit.

Comment: Thank you ver much, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[timo] have answered my question with the gist from [dannvix]:

https://gist.github.com/dannvix/dc0efdbb75bf79a79d1c#file-electron-main-js-L21-L27

here is the code:

```
// main.js for Electron
var app = require("app"),
    BrowserWindow = require("browser-window");

app.on("window-all-closed", function() {
  app.quit();
})

var mainWindow = null;
app.on("ready", function() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    center: true,
    resizable: true,
    frame: true,
    transparent: false,
  });
  mainWindow.setMenu(null);

  // create BrowserWindow with dynamic HTML content
  var html = [
    "<body>",
      "<h1>It works</h1>",
    "</body>",
  ].join("");
  mainWindow.loadURL("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(html));

  mainWindow.openDevTools();
  mainWindow.on("closed", function() {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses the DOM (Document Object Model) to interact with an HTML file.  And is executed as part of parsing the page.  Logically, you can construct an entire page using append to the html page.

`document.write("Build my page here.");`

But this solution seems cumbersome and not an advisable solution.  Perhaps, edit your question to identify your objective and I might be able to help you find the appropriate solution.